# Cannot open a file just copied to the System32 folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I'm facing a really strange behavior with Windows 7.

After copy a file to the System32 folder, in Windows 7 Ultimate x64, the file becomes a kind of ghost. It can be seen in Windows Explorer, can have its properties inspected, can be copied (successfully) from there to anywhere else, but if I try to open/access this file with any software, including notepad or regsvr32, windows says the file does not exist.

Does anyone have a clue about what is happening? Or have I found a bug in Windows 7?

Remarks:

- I've tried using local administrator, running notepad as administrator, giving all file permissions to all users among other things.
- I can open any other file in the System32 folder but the one I've copied there.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen if you *create* a file in the System32 folder as opposed to copying a file there?

Where did you copy the file from, and was it a copy or a move? I am just curious if it is retaining permissions from its original location. Have you tried removing any inherited permissions?

I have tried to reproduce your issue but I have been unable to...

Comment: I have tried coping and moving the file. If I create a file into System32, then I can open it normally, but change the permissions did not help. Thanks anyway.